# Getting more than one record for primary key in OData

Tags: odata

For the below query, I should get just one record where the primary key Id = 1, but instead I get list of all the records.

```
http://localhost:52484/Schools(1)
```

I am using Postman to query on ASP.net Web API with OData version 4.

The controller code:

```
public class SchoolsController : ODataController
{
    private readonly ISchoolService _schoolService;
    public SchoolsController(ISchoolService schoolService)
    {
        _schoolService = schoolService;
    }

    [EnableQuery(PageSize = 10,MaxExpansionDepth= 12,MaxAnyAllExpressionDepth = 5)]
    public IQueryable<School> Get()
    {
        return _schoolService.Schools();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<School> Schools()
    {
        return _schoolService.Schools();
    }
}
```

Any idea on why am getting all the records and, how to get just one?

Comment: Could you show what your controller class looks like?

Comment: @GWigWam I have updated the question with the controller code.

Answer (score 0):

You must implement a method in your controller for this:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetByKey([FromODataUri]int key)
{
    var res = _schoolService.Schools().FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == key);
    return res != null ? Ok(res) : (IActionResult)NotFound();
}
```

Comment: Where is OData implementation in this method?

Comment: @Nands I don't understand what you mean. Could you explain? You simply add this method to your controller and it should work.

Comment: The method you have given is for Web API. No doubt it would work. But we are building OData API. In your method, the query is on server side while in Odata approach the IQueryable entity is exposed through the API and the query is on the client side.

Comment: @Nands, not everything needs to be `IQueryable`, it doesn't make sense here since the result is only one item. For example see the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi/built-in-routing-conventions) (bottom of the page).